# having more than one mutable reference

Tags: rust

I am very much still learning rust and I thought I would try my hands at creating a small neural network, just to have something to sink my teeth into.

so a neural network is of course a graph with many different nodes pointing to other nodes. and it would make sense (in my mind) to structure it like this.

```rust
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Neuron<'a> {
        links: Vec<Link<'a>>,
        value: f32,
    }
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Link<'a> {
        weight: f32,
        target: &'a mut Neuron<'a>,
    }
```

but of course there is a problem with this, which is ownership since a reference can only be borrowed mutably once. So this code will fail

```rust
    let mut output = Neuron {
        value: 0.0,
        links: Vec::new(),
    };

    let a1 = Neuron {
        value: 0.0,
        links: vec![Link {
            weight: -1.49,
            target: &mut output,
        }],
    };
    let a2 = Neuron {
        value: 0.0,
        links: vec![Link {
            weight: -0.46,
            target: &mut output,
        }],
    };
```

but I don't see how it would be possible to update all linked nodes without having `target` being mutable.

so basically how do I get a function like this to be valid

```rust
    fn update_targets(neuron: &Neuron) {
        neuron.links.iter_mut().for_each(|l| {
            l.target.value = 1.0;
        })
    }
```

Comment: Graphs are especially hard in Rust, even without mutation. You may want to use a crate, e.g. [`petgraph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph).

Comment: Since you're still learning: I suggest taking a look at [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/#learn-rust-with-entirely-too-many-linked-lists). It goes over some of the pain points unique to rust that you're currently dealing with. After familiarizing yourself with the warts, I suggest finding a lib that does the heavy lifting for you, as suggested by Chayim; it wouldn't be fun writing a graph in rust for a toy project.

Comment: Side note, `&'a mut SomeType<'a>` is pretty much _always_ wrong.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/5397009 This is not exactly the same, but the lifetime `'a` in your question behaves the same as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Neural nets are very often just layers of different neurons that act on the output of the layer before them. To quote one popular library (keras, which is part of TensorFlow):

> Layers are the basic building blocks of neural networks in Keras. A
> layer consists of a tensor-in tensor-out computation function (the
> layer's call method) and some state, held in TensorFlow variables (the
> layer's weights). -- https://keras.io/api/layers/

You'll probably want something like:

```rust
// store a net as vec of layers
// this means layers cannot be generic over the size of their inputs and outputs
// and thus use slices instead of sized arrays

pub struct Net {
    layers: Vec<Layer>,
}

pub enum Layer {
    Linear(Vec<f64>, Vec<f64>, fn(&mut [f64])),
    MaxPooling(usize, usize),
    Convolution(usize, Vec<f64>, Vec<f64>, fn(&mut [f64])),
    //Flatten, // only useful as first step?
}
```

Or have some fun with one of the harder options:

```rust
// TODO: write macro to generate this code for arbitrary net

// implement each layer as a field that knows the size of its input and output
// to work around a current limitation of const generics the product of input and output length is also given)

pub struct Net<
    const LI: usize,
    const LP1: usize,
    const L1: usize,
    const LP2: usize,
    const L2: usize,
    const LP3: usize,
    const LO: usize,
> {
    layer_1: Linear<LI, L1, LP1>,
    layer_2: Linear<L1, L2, LP2>,
    layer_3: Linear<L2, LO, LP3>,
}
```

or

```rust
pub trait Layer<const L: usize> {
    fn run(&self) -> [f64; L];
}

pub struct Input<const L: usize>(pub [f64; L]);

impl<const L: usize> Layer<L> for Input<L> {
    fn run(&self) -> [f64; L] {
        self.0
    }
}

// work around restriction on using const generic expressions with extra parameter LP = LO * LI
pub struct Linear<'a, const LI: usize, const LO: usize, const LP: usize> {
    input: &'a dyn Layer<LI>,
    bias: [f64; LO],
    weight: [f64; LP],
    activation: fn(&mut [f64]),
}
```